# realloc, dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, realloc

i have the tast to take one random natural number and print out the collatz conjecture from the last number to the input. The steps to the collatz conjecture are:
(a) Start with any positive integer N.
(b) If N is odd, multiply it by 3 and add 1. (i.e. N ← 3N + 1)
(c) If N is even, divide it by 2. (i.e. N ← N/2)
(d) Repeat.
and it always ends in 4 ->2->1->4->2->1...
My Computer tells me that (projectname).exe stopped working after entering the integer.

The most important point is probably that we should allocate space for the conjecture and double it if it is used completely.

My Code is:

```
int main()
{
unsigned long int input =0;
int max =16;
long int *collatz;
collatz = malloc(max*sizeof(long int));
long int *n = NULL;
long int *u = NULL;
int counter=0;

printf("Please enter a natural number:");
scanf("%lu", input);
printf("%lu\n",input);
if (input <1)
{
    printf ("ERROR, not a natural number");
    return 1;
}

n = collatz;
*n = input;

while (*n!=1)
{
    if (counter == max)
    {
        max = max*2;
        collatz = realloc (collatz,max*sizeof(long int));
    }

    if ((*n)%2 == 1)
    {
        *n=(3*(*n))+1;
    }
    else if ((*n)%2 == 0)
    {
        *n=(*n)/2;
    }
    *u=*n;
    n=n+1;
    *n=*u;
    counter++;
    int *i =0;
    for (i=n;*i!=input;i--)
    {
        printf("%lu\t",*i);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

I suppose I got the realloc wrong, most of the other stuff is no big mistery for me (that doesn't mean there are no errors, thereprobably are).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't ever do `x = realloc(x, ...);`

Comment: why? We were encouraged to use it... @0andriy

Answer (score 0):

The fault happens on the `scanf()`.

```
$ echo 4 | ./a.out 
ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==3684==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x7f37ae1007fe bp 0x7fffb3148b60 sp 0x7fffb3148480 T0)
==3684==The signal is caused by a WRITE memory access.
==3684==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x7f37ae1007fd in _IO_vfscanf (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x5c7fd)
    #1 0x7f37ae10f72f in __isoc99_vscanf (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x6b72f)
    #2 0x433206 in __interceptor___isoc99_vscanf /home/development/llvm/3.9.0/final/llvm.src/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/../sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:1187:1
    #3 0x433206 in __interceptor___isoc99_scanf /home/development/llvm/3.9.0/final/llvm.src/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/../sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:1208
    #4 0x4e4954 in main /home/brian/tmp/collatz/coll.c:15:5
    #5 0x7f37ae0c482f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
    #6 0x418dc8 in _start (/home/brian/tmp/collatz/a.out+0x418dc8)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x5c7fd) in _IO_vfscanf
==3684==ABORTING
```

In addition, I got warnings when trying to compile, these look like they can help identify the problem:

```
$ clang -fsanitize=address -g coll.c 
coll.c:15:18: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned long *' but the argument has type 'unsigned long' [-Wformat]
    scanf("%lu", input);
           ~~~   ^~~~~
coll.c:47:15: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'int *' from 'long *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        for (i=n;*i!=input;i--)
              ^~
coll.c:49:28: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned long' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
            printf("%lu\t",*i);
                    ~~~    ^~
                    %d
3 warnings generated.
```

After fixing `scanf()` I can still see a runtime fault occurring on the `*u=*n` line.  You should fire up a debugger in order to see this problem.